# textarea.val() setting and getting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

initially, my textarea has a value of Enter Comment... set via `<textarea>Enter Comment...</textarea>`

I have a .focus like:

`$("textarea.commentTextArea").live('focus', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Enter Comment...") {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});`

and a .blur() like:

`$("textarea.commentTextArea").live('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Enter Comment..." || $(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).text("Enter Comment...");
        $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});`

However, after I set the val in the .blur() function, and try to retrieve the value using .val(), it's always returning 'Enter Comment...' as opposed to the text that was user inputted. I'm at a loss here.

Thanks for the help!

Edit- I have a more in depth selector for the "textarea", that's not the issue. It wouldn't be returning "Enter Comment" if the selector was returning null. Thanks for trying though.
Same goes with my .focus() function. I just wanted to show the core of what's going on

Comment: the `focus()` function should check if it still says "Enter comment" otherwise it'll delete what the user wrote...

Comment: this works for me...what browser are you using?

Comment: it's the same in Firefox, Chrome, IE.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have quotes around the word 'textarea' in the second statement. Also, your focus event will delete anything the user entered if they return to the textarea to edit again.

do this to solve the second problem (same trick you used on the blur event):

```
$("textarea").focus(function() { if ($(this).val() == 'Enter Comment...') $(this).val(''); });
```

Comment: sorry, the "textarea" was just to show that it was for a textarea. I have a more in depth selector there, so that's not it. Same goes with my .focus() function. I just wanted to show the core of what's going on.

Comment: The simple code you posted (with the corrections mentioned by me and others) seems to work fine. You may need to post more complete code so we can take a look.

Comment: Typcially, you would use live() when you are creating elements on the fly. COuld it be that you have multiple textareas, and your selector roturns them all? Since the val() function only works on the first item returned, you might not be getting the one you want.

Comment: When I'm getting the value of the textarea, I'm using a more indepth selector, with data attributes ie. $("textarea.commentTextArea[data_attribute='attribute_value']").val().

Comment: Are you certain that your selector is returning only one element? And it is the element that you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that `$(textarea)` is returning null -- I'm guessing that it should be `$("textarea")`. I think this is fine. I tried it out using [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jwiscarson/a55qD/1/), and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it's because you missed the quotes around the `$(textarea).blur()` method.

I've created an [example with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/AScM4/) which works.